# jQuery Too much recursion error in Magento Advanced products Options extension

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, jquery

I am using Advanced Product Options Extension (https://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html) in my magento store. Problem is when I add a product in cart and try to add different product again then I am facing too much recursion error in console in below code:

```
// for correct decorating of options

        if (typeof(decorateGeneric)!='undefined') {

            var parentDecorateGeneric = decorateGeneric;    

            decorateGeneric = function(elements, decorateParams) {

                parentDecorateGeneric(elements, decorateParams);

                dependentOptions.decorateIsLast();

            };

        }
```

For instace you can checkout here: https://delissimodeli.com/breakfast-16.html
Try to add one product in cart. After that try to add another product in cart.
Can someone help me out in this?

Thanks

Comment: This code only runs when `decorateGeneric` already exists. What is `decorateGeneric` before this piece of code is executed?

Comment: Hello @ArjenMiedema, Thanks for your reply. Actually I have debug further and found that it's not only when I add product to cart it's happening even when I open multiple products one by one in quick view. 
I have checked that magento allow only listing of configurable products on list page to add product we have to go product details page. 
So that's the problem it is not allowing to show options of all products. Is that any way that I can load all products options on category page one by one on quick view click?

Comment: Do you mean that you want customers to be able to configure a product on the overview page, like this: https://www.bodyenfitshop.nl/eiwittenwhey/eiwitshakes/? If so, this is not default Magento and requires either an extension or customisations.

Comment: Yes, somelike this.

Comment: Let me check with my colleagues if this was custom code or an extension

Comment: I asked my colleague and it is a custom extension, specifically for this client. So I can't just send the code.  I did however check the code and actually, in general, it's almost an exact copy of the functionality for a configurable product on a product detail page. So I would suggest to take a look at that, make it available for the list page and then develop the functionality you want to have on a overview page.

Comment: faced same bug, is there any cure?